# Данные после заполнения не добавляются в базу данных

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Сам код:

```
  public class UsersAuthorization : DataAccess
        {
            public bool TransferUserData(string LoginName, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName, string Email)
            {
                using (var connection = GetConnection())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        Pages.Sign.СreateAccount account = new Pages.Sign.СreateAccount();
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandText = "UsersRegistr";
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoginName", account.EnterLogin.Text);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", account.EnterPassword.Text);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", account.EnterName.Text);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", account.EnterSurname.Text);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", account.EnterEmail.Text));
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

SQL-процедура:

```
CREATE PROC UsersRegistr
@LoginName varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@FirstName varchar(50),
@LastName varchar(50),
@Email varchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Users (LoginName,Password,FirstName,LastName,Email)
    VALUES (@LoginName,@Password,@FirstName,@LastName,@Email)
```

Comment: Рекомендую взять за привычку использование синтаксиса (с обязательным указанием типа и размерности параметра) `command.Parameters.Add(
    "@LoginName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = account.EnterLogin.Text` вместо метода `AddWithValue`. Если умеете по-английски, можете почитать почему [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", LoginName);
```

и так далее

---

Вы создаете

```
Pages.Sign.СreateAccount account = new Pages.Sign.СreateAccount();
```

но как в свойствах `account`-а появятся значения - совершенно непонятно. Параметры метода `UsersAuthorization.TransferUserData` нигде не используются.

---

> `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` - а что должна возвращать эта команда?

Вы уже искали это в Google и не нашли?

Comment: все равно не добавляет данные.

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich А что добавляет? Что возвращает `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`? Почему параметры `TransferUserData` не используются?

Comment: `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` - а что должна возвращать эта команда?

Comment: `public bool TransferUserData(string LoginName, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName, string Email)
        {
            return usersAuthorization.TransferUserData(LoginName, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email);`
        } - код TransferUserData

Comment: спасибо, все исправил с Вашей помощью!